# pandas dataframe rows doesnt match its shape

Tags: python, pandas

I am doing Kaggle house prices competition.
I have split the features into numeric and categorical to deal with their NaN separately.

I have filled categorical data's NaN with 'None' and there are duplicates in the rows of categorical features.

If I print out its shape, it shows correctly as (2919,43)
However, If I print its `tail`, the rows ended at 1458, where are all the missing rows?

I found out this problem because `InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects` popped up when I tried to concate the numeric features and the categorical features by running `X = pd.concat([X_numeric, X_categorical], axis=1,ignore_index=True)`.

[image]

Comment: Try using `X_categorical.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)` before checking `X_categorical.tail(3)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your index is probably messed up. Add these lines of code:

```
X_categorical = X_categorical.reset_index(drop=True)
X_numeric = X_numeric.reset_index(drop=True)

X_categorical.tail(3)
```

Comment: actually, i saved the X_categorical to csv and found out that the index reset to 0 when it reaches half of the data. The weird thing is that `X_numerical` and `X_categorical` ran the same codes but only `X_categorical` got index messed up

Comment: It happens. Perhaps you concatenated two dataframes together?